# How do you get an Exception thrown by an Task started from the UI thread (so it is not allowed to block with await)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

The goal is to start a Task, that loads some resources from the disk, on the UI thread, and then when it is finished to check if it threw an Exception without blocking the UI thread, and if it did, to rethrow the exception on the UI thread so the program ends and I get a stack trace.

I have been able to figure out that I can start a Task on a background thread without blocking, and awaiting the Task blocks the main thread.

I absolutely can not call await on the Task, because it would block the UI thread, but it appears I need to call it to access the Exception property after the Task has completed. I also can not use continueWith, because that also runs asynchronously, so propagating the exception from there will not work.

The docs I see all block to wait for the Exception.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0#WaitingForOne

For the Exception property of the Task, it would be nice if I could use something like RegisterPropertyChangedCallback, but that is not an available method in the Task object.

This is the code where I want to rethrow an Exception in the UI thread without blocking it

```cs
        public TitlePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            string baseFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string folder = baseFolder + @"Assets\";
            Task task = DataSource.Load(folder);
            // This is where I want to rethrow the Exception if it was thrown
            // unless I can end the program and print the stack trace
            // from the Task when it throws an Exception.
            // Note that this is inside the constructor of a Page class; 
            // it is vital that the UI thread is not blocked.
        }
```

Comment: Throwing exceptions from constructors is a bad idea in the first place. Move the code to some event that can be async so that you can use await there

Comment: How do I propagate the Exception from another async method to the UI thread though?

Comment: When you use await in the UI thread (like an async event). the exception is handled in the UI thread.

Comment: What UI framwork do you use and what type is TitlePage?

Comment: await blocks though

Comment: I am using winui3, and it is a Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page

Comment: await does not block the UI thread from responding to user input. It does pause execution of the current method though - is that what you mean?

Comment: Huh, it does not. I thought it did.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is actually a nested Task, and that looks like an easy fix.

Comment: What do you mean by nested task?

Comment: async method called another async method. Adding await did cause the Exceptions to be propagated, and I do not understand how await does not block the thread if await has to wait for the results of the method.

Comment: That's the entire purpose of await :) Microsoft has some well-written articles on [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) that are worth the read.

Comment: But in short, await pauses execution of the method and schedules the rest to run when the task is complete. It's kind of like putting the rest of the method inside a `ContinueWith()`, but so much easier to work with.

Comment: Is the `TitlePage` the main page of the application, or it's a secondary page that appears when a button is clicked on the main page?

Comment: It is the main page

Comment: If it's the main page, then why are you bothering about not-blocking the UI thread? The application has no UI before showing the first page! At least that's what I know about WinForms applications.

Answer (score 3):

Use a "factory method": a static method that returns a new instance of the class. Then make the constructor empty and private to prevent anyone from creating an instance without using the factory method.

Something like this:

```
private TitlePage() {}

public static async Task<TitlePage> CreateTitlePage()
{
    var titlePage = new TitlePage();
    titlePage.InitializeComponent();

    string baseFolder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string folder = baseFolder + @"Assets\";
    Task task = DataSource.Load(folder);
    
    await task;
    return titlePage;
}
```

Because this static method is inside the class, you can call other private methods, including the constructor.

Then you call it like this:

```
var newTitlePage = await TitlePage.CreateTitlePage();
```

If it is called on the UI thread, any exception will be thrown on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Rethrowing within the UI thread an exception that was thrown by a side-task is just a special case of the more general case of communicating to the UI thread any kind of result produced by the side-task.

(In other words, today you think you only need to throw an exception; tomorrow you are likely to discover that you also need to obtain a result.)

For this purpose I like to communicate a `Result` class like the one found in Scala, (and of which various implementations exist for C#,) but this is not necessary; the `Task` object can also be communicated after `Task.IsCompleted` becomes true; The UI thread can check whether it represents failure with `Task.IsFaulted`, and if so, it can get the exception with `Task.Exception`; otherwise, it can get the result with `Task<T>.Result`.

So, the question now becomes how to have a `Task` communicate a result back to the UI thread, once the task is complete, without the UI thread having to wait for the task to complete.

To do this, you can pass to the task a "task completion action" in the form of an `Action<R>` delegate, where R is the type of the result, and to implement this delegate in such a way that it ***posts*** the result into the message queue of the UI thread.

Under WPF, posting something into the UI thread is done with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`.

So, here is some code:

```
using Sys = System;
using Wpf = System.Windows;
using WpfThreading = System.Windows.Threading;

private void TaskCompletionAction( R result )
{
    Assert( not-in-UI-thread );
    Sys.Action action = () => ReceiveResult( result );
    Wpf.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        WpfThreading.DispatcherPriority.Background, 
        action );
}

private void ReceiveResult( R result )
{
    Assert( in-UI-thread );
    ...do something with the result...
}
```